# Bitwise Operators - how to?

Tags: android

When setting some view properties in Android bitwise operators are used, for example, setting `EditText` input type. Kotlin uses `or` and Java uses `|`.

```
input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES or InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)
```

How does it work under the hood? Why `||` is not used?

Comment: There are 2 versions of the AND and the OR operators. One is the *logical* version (used in comparisons). The other one is the *bitwise* version, used mostly for bitmasking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the method `setRawInputType` as accepting a bunch of bits, instead of an integer value. There are many methods like this one. This pattern is used when the method wants the caller to specify a bunch of "options". By passing `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES or InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`, you are passing this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0001
```

See the two `1`s? Now let's look out the values of `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES` and `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT`:

```
InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES
0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000

InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
```

If we do the OR operation on each of those bits, we get `0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0001`.

The method basically checks which bits are 1s and does different stuff based on that. By using the `|` or `or` operator, you are kind of saying "I want this bit and this bit to be `1`". So by saying `or`, you actually mean "and". Counterintuitive, huh?

The `||` operator only works for `boolean` operands because it is a logical operator, so it can't be used here.

Answer (score 0):

The `or` in Kotlin and `|` in Java used with numbers are not related to boolean operators (`bool1 | bool2` and `bool1 || bool2`). These are [bitwise operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#operations). The bit operators in Kotlin are defined as `infix` functions, see `or`:

```
public infix fun or(other: Int): Int
```

As a result you can execute this function in two ways:

```
result1 = number1.or(number2)
result2 = number1 or number2
```

Answer (score 0):

`||` is a boolean OR operator. It evaluates the first expression and if that first expression is true, it won't execute the second.

```
if (someCondition() || someActualEvaluation()) //someActualEvaluation() won't run
```

The logic of this sort of looks like the following (although it doesn't actually create new methods in bytecode):

```
public void conditionContainer() {
    if (someCondition()) {
        condition();
        return;
    }

    if (someActualEvaluation()) {
        condition();
        return;
    }
}

public void condition() {
    //whatever is in the condition
}
```

---

`|` is the bitwise OR operator. It works with boolean expressions

```
if (true | someActualEvaluation()) //someActualEvaluation() will run
```

But it also works with integers, longs, bytes, etc. Bitwise OR will look at the bits of the numbers and compare each corresponding bit using the binary OR operation. For example, using `5` and `3`:

```
5 --> 0101
3 --> 0011
```

Using the OR operation on each bit, we get `0111`, or decimal `7`.

`|` works on booleans, because, at the binary level, a boolean is either `1` or `0`. So if you have

```
if (true | false)
```

You're running `1 OR 0`, which is `1`/`true`.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) has more details.

---

In short, `||` and `|` aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 
`|`, `&`, `^`, `~`, `<<`, `>>` and `>>>` are bitwise operators and  `||`, `&&` and `!` are logical ones.

**What's the difference?**
Logical operators like `&&`, `!=` or `||` can only be used with boolean operands and will abort remaining evaluation as soon as result is decided.

```
| Operator |                        What it does                               |
|:--------:|:-----------------------------------------------------------------:|
|     &&   |     Will only return true if both operands are true               |
|     ||   |     Will return true if either operand is true                    |
|     ~    |     Will return true if operand is false and false if it is true  |
```

Bitwise operators like AND (`&`), OR (`|`) or XOR (`^`) will evaluate every bit of both operands according to the operator's logic and can be applied to integral types as well (int, short, byte, long, char).

```
| Operator |                        What it does                               |               i.e.              |
|:--------:|:-----------------------------------------------------------------:|:-------------------------------:|
|     &    |     Bitwise AND, will set bit if both operands have it            |  0011 & 1010 will produce 0010  |
|     |    |     Bitwise OR, will set a  bit if either of operands has it      |  0011 | 1010 will produce 1011  |
|     ~    |     Bitwise complement, it is a unary   operator, takes one       | ~01010101 will produce 10101010 |
|          |            operand, inverts operand's bit pattern                 |                                 |    
|     ^    |     Bitwise XOR, will set bit if only one of the operators has it |   0011^1010 will produce 1001   |
|    <<    |     Left shift operator, moves the left's  operand value to the   |  1010 << 2 will produce 101000  |
|          |       left by  a number of bits specified in the right operand    |                                 |        
|    >>    |     Right shift. Same as above,  but value is moved to the right  |    1010 >> 2 will produce 10    |
```

More or less, the same applies to Kotlin disregarding the syntax